# Angular ui-router resolve - using $state.go

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

Im just learning ui-router resolve and would like to simply redirect my state if the user is not logged-in.

It seems I cannot simply use `$state.go` inside the callback function.

Here is my code:

```
.state('base.user', {
  url: '/user',
  templateUrl: 'views/user.html',
  controller: 'userCtrl',
  resolve: {
    test: function($state, $q) {
      var deferred = $q.defer();
      if (!loggedIn()) { // resolves to false when not logged-in
        deferred.reject();
        $state.go('base.test'); // ** Throws "Possibly unhandled rejection" error
      } else {
        deferred.resolve();
        /* and maybe do some more stuff.. */
      }
    }
  }
})
```

I know this is often done with services and things like that, but for now, I would just like a simple working example.

Answer (score 2):

The way we decided to handle it was to listen to `$stateChangeError` and if the error thrown contained a path, then go to that path.

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeError', function(toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams, error) {
  if (error.state) {
    $state.go(error.state, error.stateParams);
  }
});
```

And in you resolve:

```
test: function($q) {
  var deferred = $q.defer();
  if (!loggedIn()) {
    deferred.reject({state: 'base.test'});
  } else {
    deferred.resolve();
  }
  return deferred.promise;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Implement the $stateChangeStart hook and check your redirection condition there

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, toState) {      
     if (toState.name === 'base.user') {              
       if(!loggedIn()) { // Check if user allowed to transition                  
            event.preventDefault();   // Prevent migration to default state                  
            $state.go('base.test');           
        }
      }
});
```